# Site abre na pasta webroot

Tags: php, cakephp

O site que estou a colocar online está a apresentar `http://mysite.com/app/webroot/` sempre que se coloca `www.mysite.com` no caminho para o aceder. No entanto eu queria que ele apenas fosse para `http://mysite.com/`, onde está a view `Home.ctp`.

Estou a utilizar a versão 2.4.4 do Cake.

**htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Como está o seu arquivo `.htaccess`?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Editei a pergunta.

Comment: Agora preciso do seu arquivo `apache\conf\httpd.conf`.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Eu não sei ainda aceder ao `httpd.conf` do servidor, mas o mod rewrite está a funcionar, a instalação do cake pelo menos assim dizia.

Comment: Já verificou o arquivo `routes.php`? Veja se está assim: `Router::connect( '/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'home') );`

Comment: @IgorMartins Sim e a rota está correcta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há duas maneiras de resolver isso:

### 1) Cpanel/Plesk

Crie um redirecionamento de toda requisição com `http://www` para `http://push...`.

Por exemplo.. na **BlueHost** você faz isso nesta página (é praticamente a mesma operação em todos os Cpanels).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que você **deve selecionar** neste caso é seu domínio, e **não deixar** selecionado "All Domains", caso contrário, todas as requisições neste servidor serão redirecionadas para a URL que você informou abaixo.

Fora isso, **abaixo** há alguns radio buttons, os quais você seleciona se quer redirecionar apenas quando a URL **tiver www**, em ambos os casos ou não redirecionar o www.

---

### 2) .htaccess

No seu `.htaccess` da raiz (o primeiro), faça o seguinte:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

   RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

---

Escolha uma das maneiras acima e teste.

Qualquer dúvida, deixe um comentário abaixo.

Comment: O ``home.ctp`` esta na pasta ``View\Home\``, e a rota é `Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'home'));`. O htaccess também está nos sítios correctos.

Comment: Entendi qual é o problema.... já vou editar a questão.

Comment: Utilizei a segunda opção e funcionou ás mil maravilhas. Muito Obrigado!

Comment: Precisando estamos ai.